# Why is the following Python code wrong?

Tags: python

I have the following problem for my assignment:

> Write a program that prints the longest substring of `s` in which the letters occur in alphabetical order. For example, if `s = azcbobobegghakl`, then your program should print:
>
> ```
> Longest substring in alphabetical order is: beggh
> ```

The code I wrote for the problem is this:

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'

current_index = 1
first_index = 0

result_string = ''
current_string = s[first_index]

while current_index < len(s):
    if ord(s[first_index]) <= ord(s[current_index]):
        current_string += s[current_index]
    elif ord(s[current_index]) < ord(s[first_index]):
        current_string = ''

    if len(current_string) > len(result_string):
        result_string = current_string[:]

    current_index += 1
    first_index += 1

print('Longest substring in alphabetical order is: ' + result_string)
```

The code doesn't give out the correct result, for some reason, it gives out `eggh` instead of `beggh`.
And since this is an assignment, I do not ask that you give me the corrected code, but just give me an hint on where I am wrong since I wanna solve my problem BY MYSELF and don't wanna cheat.

Thanks.

Comment: Dejavu, I'm sure that this question has been answered before.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac May you provide me the link to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is here:

```
current_string = ''
```

you should not clear it when you find `s[current_index]) < s[first_index]`.

### Other hints:

1. no need to use `ord`.
2. what happens if `s='a'`?
3. no need to copy `result_string = current_string[:]`, since strings are immutables

Hints OVER ;P

Comment: Thank you! I replaced it with this `current_string = s[current_index]` and it worked! Though, it fails for the input `'zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba'` Any idea how to overcome this problem? Note: answer should be `z` and not `y`.

Comment: P.S. Thanks but really, other hints weren't required. :)

Comment: Solved! Ha, initialized result to s[first_index] and done! :D

Comment: @user3243703 on your first comment, hint2 is needed ;)

Comment: Use the code again, modify it using the specs specified in the previous comments; it actually works now!